# Convert varchar field back to time datatype field with hh:mm:ss:ms format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Please tell me how to re-convert below one in SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
select replace(Convert (varchar(8), GetDate(), 108), ':', '');
```

I converted a `DATETIME` datatype column to `nvarchar` without any format. It's just `hhmmssms`.

I want to get my time value back with `hh:mm:ss:ms` format. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
declare @VarTime as int = replace(Convert (varchar(8),GetDate(), 108),':','')

select convert(time,convert(varchar(2),(@VarTime / 10000) % 100) +':'+
       convert(varchar(2),(@VarTime / 100) % 100)+':'+
       convert(varchar(2),right(@VarTime,2)))
```

### Output:

`12:28:45`

**EDIT:** If you have date like `hhmmssms`

```
set @VarTime = '11223344'
select convert(varchar(2),(@VarTime / 1000000) % 100) +':'+
       convert(varchar(2),(@VarTime / 10000) % 100) +':'+
       convert(varchar(2),(@VarTime / 100) % 100)+':'+
       convert(varchar(2),right(@VarTime,2))
```

Comment: OP asked that? anyways we have Casting. Isn't it?

Comment: You won't do that as long as my answer is satisfying OP's concern. But you are master of your choice so go on. Fyi, Op's own query is eliminating `ms` part.

Comment: Hello Pravin , Sorry for late reply. IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM. THANKS ALOT. THAT IS What Im looking for.